# Scrum-based hardware design

Tags: project-management, hardware

My current project involves hardware design with Scrum as work method.

I'm looking for software which allows me to create work items, merge them, split them, combine them, categorise, etc.

I'm particularly interested in the management of user stories and requirements. There are requirements I know which I have a solution for, requirements I know that I don't have a solution. There are also requirements which are currently unknown, but have a specified topic (security, protocols, etc.). I want to list/categorise those requirements and link them with my work items.

Does any such software exist?

I don't care about stylish user interfaces as long as they're functional.
Either Windows or Linux based.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! I only know Scrum for the Software-Development side, how does that differ from the hardware side?

Comment: @AngeloFuchs Not much, except it's a pain in the behind to find finished products at the end of a sprint. Afar from that, Scrum doesn't care if you develop software or hardware.

Comment: Have you take a look at [Version One](http://www.versionone.com/).  We use it for software projects, but, it seems like it can be adapted to your needs.

Comment: @rrirower It's definitely into the right direction, but I can't drop my requirements in it the way I want.